# String based command ubuntu

Tags: command, ubuntu-16.04

how to find a string that contained specific substring in a file using commands in ubuntu?
eg  I love to bake and eat a cake.
my command should find words ending with 'ke' (i.e cake and bake) and display it

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched for and read about? There are quite literally tens of thousands of tutorials and references about Linux (and POSIX) command-line handling and the commands that can be used to handle text.

Comment: I have tried grep -r xyz abc.txt > result.txt  in this command it return whole line containing the string .All i want is to return the substring of a string.

Answer (score 0):

For this a combination of [`sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) and [`grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) could work:

```
$ echo "I love to bake and eat a cake" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep ke$
bake
cake
```

The `sed` command replaces space with newlines, then the `grep` command looks for lines ending with `ke`.